# Task Scheduler Launching openwith.exe program instead of PowerShell script

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I've have created a Powershell script that automatically connects to office 365 and sets all users default calendar permissions to reviewer. this script runs perfectly when executed manually.

but

I am trying to launch the powershell script via task scheduler on WS-2012-R2.

i run the task but when i check a test users calendar permissions its still the same "contributor".

When task scheduler starts the task, it creates a process, that process is given a process ID.

i went to check the ID in task manager it showed as "Pick an App" under the processes tab.

i right clicked and clicked details and it shows as OpenWith.exe

i checked file association and (.PS1) is associated to WindowsPowershell

i went to the scripts file location in explorer, Rclicked and changed the OPenWith from POwershell to Windows Powershell ISE and i still get the same thing when i run through task sheduler. ("pick and app & OPenWith.exe")

i have tried editing the "actions" in Task Manager to a combination of things such as.

In task shceduler properties

Program/script: was set to: C:\Powershell script\default reviewer permissions
this doesnt work

then i changed that to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\POwershell and also PowerShell_ise

with C:\Powershell script\default reviewer permissions in the "add arguments (optional) section.

and visa versa

Can anyone please tell me what i can do to make this script run.

Many thanks

Comment: What happens when you launch powershell from a command-line like:`powershell -?` as this should show the syntax needed?  You should be using something like: `PowerShell -File "D:\WORK\ps\webtest.ps1"` for your tasks.

Comment: When i run "Powershell -?" i get syntax suggestions. in "actions" Tab i changed the Program/Script to PowerShell and in the add arguments field i entered -File "C:\Powershell script\Default Reviewer permissions.ps1" and it worked. many thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add "comment has something useful" to this?  Or, I can check with the Moderator to see if I can break out my comment as an answer.  I think I may have made the mistake as adding as a comment.  I will check with the Moderator either way..  I don't think this will be the last time we will see this issue.  :)

Comment: "comment has something useful"

Comment: Thanks Daniel..  There is a actually a "scoring" to the left of comments or better yet,  if you look a the answer I provided maybe more in line.  I apologize for originally not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you launch PowerShell from a command-line (CMD and not a PowerShell Session) like:

```
powershell -?
```

as this should show the syntax needed?

For example, mine shows (Removing the extra help information):

> PowerShell
>       [-File  ]

Specifically:

> -File
>       Execute a script file.

You should be using something like in your Scheduled Task (note: the use of quotes as well):

```
PowerShell -File "D:\WORK\ps\webtest.ps1"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped me trying to run a script via Task Scheduler, the issue was I was simply pointing to the script, hence 'OpenWith.exe' was showing up. Broadly speaking I changed it to `CMD "Script"` and that got it, it is now running a command prompt that can run the script (i.e. knows what to open the script with)